# SO chat: how to make the sidebar not respond to scroll event?

Tags: html, css

I am using chat feature of chat.stackoverflow.com... It's really amazing!
I am curious, when I scroll the window, the right side of the chat room(div id="sidebar") didn't respond to the scroll event at all, how that can be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed positioning.

```
#sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 28%;
}
```

Comment: can you answer more accurately? How to write the css/html for that?